# Access-Control-Allow-Origin problems on the same domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, xmlhttprequest, same-origin-policy

How is it possible that when I try to make an XMLHTTPRequest from a javascript file to a web service located on the very same domain, I get:

Origin http://mydomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin ???

If I change mydomain.com to localhost, I no longer have problems, but I would like to keep it  as mydomain.com

What do I have to edit, and why in the first place, since it's the same domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)  look in your request/response headers. Is the server returning a weird `access-control-allow-origin` header?

2) It's not just the domain, it's also the protocol (http vs https vs ftp etc), the port (if you have a :8080 or something like that), and potentially the part after the .com/

Comment: true, the port to the webservices is different - 26438. But the domain is the same, plus I make sure call it with the special port

Comment: if the port you are calling via xhr is different than the port of the url on which the js was loaded, the request will be stopped.

Answer (score 5):

It probably is because of the missing www. If you test with yourdomain.com and your site is at www.yourdomain.com it is concidered cross-domain and cross-domain calls are not allowed by default.